# How can I make all optional OpenAPI parameters nullable using springdoc-openapi?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi, springdoc

The [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org) library automatically marks certain properties as [required](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#required) in the generated OpenAPI documentation.  For instance, properties annotated as `@NotNull` will be included in the list of required properties in the generated YAML file.

One thing the library does not do is mark optional properties as [`nullable: true`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#null).  However, by default a Spring Boot application will accept `null` in requests and return `null` in responses for optional properties.  This means that there is a discrepancy between the OpenAPI documentation and the behavior of the endpoint.

It is trivial to manually mark any individual property as nullable: just add `@Schema(nullable = true)` to the field or accessor.  However, in a large model with multiple properties, I would rather this be automatically determined in the same manner as the `required` property.  Namely, if the property is not required, I would want it to be `nullable`, and vice versa.

How can I get my optional properties marked as `nullable: true` in OpenAPI documentation generated by springdoc-openapi?

### Example

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class RequiredExample {
    @NotNull
    private String key;

    private String value;

    public String getKey() { return key; }
    public void setKey(String key) { this.key = key; }
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

### Generated OpenAPI documentation:

```json
"components": {
  "schemas": {
    "RequiredExample": {
      "required": [
        "key"
      ],
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Desired OpenAPI documentation:

```json
"components": {
  "schemas": {
    "RequiredExample": {
      "required": [
        "key"
      ],
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "string"
          "nullable": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution? Also do you know *why* `"nullable": true` hasn't been made the default for optional properties?

Comment: @Snackoverflow I haven't found anything built-in, so I've been using the [`OpenApiCustomizer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69310599/1108305) approach.  And I don't know why they made the decision to make things nullable by default.

Comment: This is especially interesting for Kotlin, because there you have explicit nullable or non-nullable types. Turns out if you have a nullable property, then springdoc-openapi makes it optional (not required) but still not nullable. So according to the schema you can omit the property from JSON, but you may not have its value `null`. As of now, I am still not sure whether this is intended or a bug. Haven't really found any explanation online.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a springdoc-openapi [`OpenApiCustomiser`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-common/1.5.10/org/springdoc/core/customizers/OpenApiCustomiser.html) Spring bean which sets all properties to `nullable` unless they are in the list of `required` properties.  This approach benefits from the built-in springdoc-openapi support for `@NotNull` and other such annotations, since the `required` property will have been calculated in the standard manner based on the presence of such properties.

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema;
import org.springdoc.core.customizers.OpenApiCustomiser;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class NullableIfNotRequiredOpenApiCustomizer implements OpenApiCustomiser {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public void customise(OpenAPI openApi) {
        for (Schema schema : openApi.getComponents().getSchemas().values()) {
            if (schema.getProperties() == null) {
                continue;
            }

            ((Map<String, Schema>) schema.getProperties()).forEach((String name, Schema value) -> {
                if (schema.getRequired() == null || !schema.getRequired().contains(name)) {
                    value.setNullable(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you should handle `ComposedSchema` types differently. For example, if your schema has an `allOf` attribute with an object inside, the properties of that nested object should also be processed. The above code does not do so and just skips them because their `getProperties()` will return `null`.

Comment: @Snackoverflow That is likely true, and something I'll have to play around with when I get the opportunity.  My code doesn't use `ComposedSchema` currently, so I haven't run into this myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could directly annotate your attribute with `@Schema`. The key here is that both `nullable` and `requiredMode` will have to bet set.

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class RequiredExample {
    @NotNull
    private String key;

    @Schema(nullable = true, requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
    private String value;

    public String getKey() { return key; }
    public void setKey(String key) { this.key = key; }
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

For some context, [this](https://github.com/anymaniax/orval/issues/862) was my exact use case.

Comment: Yep, that's something I mentioned in my question, and something I didn't want to have to do for every single property: "It is trivial to manually mark any individual property as nullable: just add `@Schema(nullable = true)` to the field or accessor. However, in a large model with multiple properties, I would rather this be automatically determined in the same manner as the `required` property."

Comment: Makes sense. In that case, I would consider creating an own custom class annotation that will apply the nullable part to all fields, if they don't have a `@Schema` annotation already. Not sure how much work that would be though.